# How can i filter JSON data?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to filter some JSON data.

This is the JSON:

```
[
  {
    "image": "categories/x.png",
    "_id": "x",
    "id": "x",
    "name": "name1",
    
  },
  {
    "image": "categories/category_404.png",
    "_id": "x",
    "id": "x",
    "name": "name2",
    
  },
  {
    "image": "categories/x.png",
    "_id": "x",
    "id": "x",
    "name": "name3",
   
  }
]
```

I want to exclude the second object and show only the first and the last one.

The next code is the way i output it to the site:

```
    const data = axios.get('url')
        .then(response => {
            const products = response.data;
            res.render('shop/subcategories/products-layout', {products});
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

how do i exclude the second object by their name

Comment: You can at first parse it (`JSON.parse`) and afterwards work with the result object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.filter` for that:

```js
const objects = [
  {
    "image": "categories/x.png",
    "_id": "x",
    "id": "x",
    "name": "name1",
    
  },
  {
    "image": "categories/category_404.png",
    "_id": "x",
    "id": "x",
    "name": "name2",
    
  },
  {
    "image": "categories/x.png",
    "_id": "x",
    "id": "x",
    "name": "name3",
   
  }
];

const res = objects.filter(o=>o.image === 'categories/x.png');

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hi, tnx, I edited the code. I tried the filter method but I can't make it work..